# jax-rx Client post receive both JSON and Cookie how?

Tags: java, cookies, jax-rs

I've made a simple client request with jax-rx client - using post.

```
ResponseContainer container = new ResponseContainer();
WebTarget oxipTarget = ClientBuilder.newClient().target(fullAuthUrl);
container = oxipTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).header("SQLREPORTS","DSALLOWED")
                        .post(Entity.entity(form.asMap(), MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED),ResponseContainer.class);
```

So this works perfectly for me. But I also need to read a cookie from 'Set-Cookie' - but I don't have the full response. How to get access to the 'Set-Cookie' ? I'm using Wildfly and if I read the full response instead of reading the actual data into `ResponseContainer`, then I can't seem to get access to the actual data by the `getEntity` method, which seems to be the only available method on the response instance.

kind regards

Torben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `Response`, then read the body with [`Response.readEntity(Class type)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#readEntity%28java.lang.Class%29). [`post`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/SyncInvoker.html#post%28javax.ws.rs.client.Entity%29) is overloaded, with options to return a `Response` or the entity body object (by specifying the class type as the second argument, as you are doing). If you don't specify the response entity type (as the second argument), it will return `Response`

```
Response response = target.request().post(Entity.entity(..));
ResponseContainer container = response.readEntity(ResponseContainer.class);
Map<String, NewCookie> cookies = response.getCookies();
response.close();
```

Comment: I'm using Intellij and as I wrote it doesn't show me the possibility to user readEntity(ResponseContainer.class). I only have getEntity on response. It's Resteasy 3.0.8 Final provided by Wildfly

Comment: Then you must be using the wrong `Response` class. Make sure it's [`javax.ws.rs.core.Response`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html). This class has been available since JAX-RS 1.0, so Resteasy 3.x.x will have it.

Comment: Correction: [`Response.readEntity`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#readEntity%28java.lang.Class%29), is part of JAX-RS 2.0, which Resteasy 3.x.x implements

Comment: I'm curious if you are using the Java EE 6 API (which won't have this method). If you can't get it working, can you update your post to show your dependencies.

Comment: Well actually the client API you're using _is_ the 2.0 client API, so there should be no reason for it not to have the `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` class

Comment: Hi, You got me looking at my Pom I had the resteasy - correct one - and a JBoss api spec 1.0 - this was what gave me the problem - so now I can se the readEntity. I initially used some tool to generate the pom - maybe it was added this way.